# Physical meaning of solutions to 2-d inhomogeneous heat equation with inhomogeneous BC's

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose one is trying to solve this equation,

$$ \frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x^{2}} + \frac{q}{\kappa} = \frac{\partial U}{\partial t} $$

why is it that we seek solutions of the form

$$U(x,t) = \Psi (x,t) + \phi(x)$$

I am trying to understand the underlying motivation for seeking solutions of this form. Also, what is the physical meaning of $\Psi(x,t)$ and $\phi(x)$, I would very much appreciate it if you could explain it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi(x)$ is the steady state solution that is approached at very long times.  It satisfies the differential equation with the time derivative set to zero.  It also satisfies the boundary conditions.  $\Psi(x,t)$ is the transient part of the solution which dies out at long times.  It satisfies the differential equation without the source term, with homogeneous boundary conditions, and with an initial condition equal to that of U minus $\phi$

Comment: +1 Do you think this decomposition into steady and transient part would still be useful if the boundary conditions were changing with time?

Comment: It might be if you could represent the solution starting with the solution with constant boundary conditions and using a convolution integral.

Comment: Will this type of separation of variables hold also for Robin boundary conditions? Also, are you implying that the solution $\phi(x)$ is the transient solution because if we assume time independence, it dies out? In that case, wouldn't the system turn into something like $u''(x)=-\frac{q(U)}{k}$?

Comment: I don't know how to say it more clearly: $\phi$ is the final steady state solution at long times.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense now. It took me a while.